# CSS expand <p> to fit text inside absolutely positioned parent?

Tags: html, css

Here is a codepen with my issue http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNWEvQ.

HTML:

```
<div class="dialog-wrapper">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dialog-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

.dialog {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 80%;

  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Why does the p tag not expand to the width of the text and force .dialog and .dialog-wrapper to expand as well?

Is there CSS that can make the paragraph expand as I desire?

Comment: um what do you want? everything to expand together?

Comment: I want the p and .dialog to expand to wrap the paragraph contents while .dialog-wrapper to expand so that .dialog is 80% of .dialog-wrapper's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.dialog-wrapper` is absolutely positioned and all `left`, `right` and `width` are `auto`, its `width` will be determined by the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm. Basically, it will be the width of the text.

Then, if you use `max-width: 80%` on a child, that will be smaller than the width of the text. So the text will overflow, or it will break into multiple lines.

Instead, you should add some margin:

```css
.dialog {
  margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dialog-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
.dialog {
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 10%;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.wrapper2 {
  top: 100px;
}
.wrapper2 p {
  width: 253px;
}
.wrapper3 {
  top: 200px;
}
.wrapper3 p {
  width: 315px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog-wrapper">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog-wrapper wrapper2">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog-wrapper wrapper3">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .dialog {   max-width: 100%;  }
and both they will expand.

Comment: I want .dialog to be { max-width: 80% }.

Comment: What about using   overflow: auto;  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.dialog-wrapper {
  display: table;
  // add other properties
}

.dialog {
  display: table-cell;
  // add other properties
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
 // add other properties
}
```

Now the parent container `dialog-wrapper` will now adjust to the width of the child elements, i.e. `dialog` and `p`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `word-wrap:break-word` on the style for `p`.
- Remove fixed widths of `p`. You may also want to give your
  `.dialog-wrapper` a fixed width.
- codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwjddX